# Getting Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop, even after fixing

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've been working on college project and its giving me this 'Too many re-renders error again and again. Although i've changed all onClick function to arrow functions which prevent Too many re-renders error but its still giving me same error
My Source Code:

import React, {useState} from 'react'

import Dropdown from 'react-mui-multiselect-dropdown'

import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField'

import Icon from '@material-ui/core/Icon'

import { Paper, Grid, Typography, makeStyles, Button } from '@material-ui/core'

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ( {

```
button: {
  margin: theme.spacing(1),
}, }))
```

const useStyles2 = makeStyles((theme) => ({

```
error: {
  color: theme.palette.error.dark,
  fontSize: '1em'
},
checkBox: {
  color: 'Purple'
}}))



function AddReview() {

const [value1, setValue1]= useState("")

const [res, setRes]= useState("")

const [review, setReview]= useState("")

const [items, setItems]=useState([])

const addItem=()=>{
    setItems([...items, {
        id: items.length,
        restr: res,
        rate: value1,
        review: review

    }])

}
const inputProps = {
    step: 300,
  };
const classes = useStyles();
const classes2 = useStyles2();
const [selectedEmployee, setSelectedEmployees] = useState([])
const [employees, setEmployees] = useState([])
const employeesData = [
  { id: 1, name: 'Bhushan' },
  { id: 2, name: 'Vishal' },
  { id: 3, name: 'Ravindra' }
]
setEmployees(employeesData)
const SelectedEmp = []
setSelectedEmployees(SelectedEmp)
return (
    <div>
    <div style={{backgroundColor: "grey"}}>
        <a>Enter Restaurant Name: </a><input value={res} onChange={e => setRes(e.target.value)}></input><br></br>
        <a>Rate: </a>
        <Typography
            variant='h6'
            style={{ color: 'tomato', marginTop: '1em' }}
          >
            Single Select
          </Typography>
          <Dropdown
            data={employees}
            fullWidth
            searchable
            searchPlaceHolder='search employee...'
            itemId='id'
            itemLabel='name'
            simpleValue
            searchByValue='name'
            itemValue='id'
            title="Select Employee"
            selectedValues={selectedEmployee}
            customStyles={{
              error: classes2.error,
              checkBox: classes2.checkBox
            }}
            errorText='error'
            onItemClick={(records) => {
              setSelectedEmployees(records)
            }}
            onDeleteItem={(deleted) => {
              console.log('deleted', deleted)
            }}
          /><br></br>
        
        <a>Review: </a><TextField value={review} id="time"  type="text" inputProps={inputProps} onChange={(e) => setReview(e.target.value)}/>
        <br></br>
        <Button variant="contained"
        color="primary"
        className={classes.button}
        onClick={() => addItem}
        
        >
    Post
  </Button>
  </div>

  <ul>
{items.map(item=>(<li key={item.id}>Restaurant Name: {item.restr}<br/> Rated: {item.rate} Review: {item.review}</li>))}
  </ul>

    </div>
)}
```

export default AddReview

Comment: Use hooks for setEmployees for setting data. You could use useEffect, read about it and then use it as per your requirement. setEmployees causing infinite loop update.

Comment: onClick={() => addItem} should be onClick={() => addItem()}